# How to create a Toolbar in Kendo Ui Web

Tags: kendo-ui

I have some UI requirements that are best meet by a toolbar where options functions like radio button.  That is, clicking one option, unclicks the other.

I've looked at using Mobil Button Group.  I would prefer to have a solution that didn't use the Mobil controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo UI Web doesn't include such a widget yet. This is part of our future plans.

Comment: That is what I thought.  I was a little perplexed about this as there is an internal toolbar used Grid & Schedule widget.

Comment: Atanas, do you have a rough idea when this may get delivered? I'm evaluating Kendo UI Web and it would be useful for us too.